# SQL STORE PROCEDURE

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, procedure

What is the Problem This code sql server?

> syntax error :Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6 Incorrect syntax near '('.

```
BEGIN TRAN

exec trn_siparis_insert 'Database',348

exec trn_boyutlu_siparis_olustur , @siparis_id=Select id FROM TABLE.dbo.siparis where kayit_tarihi=(SELECT MAX(kayit_tarihi) FROM TABLE.dbo.siparis ) , @TargetDb=Database

COMMIT TRAN
```

Comment: You could make the task easier for yourself and us if you format the statement so that it is easier to read.

Comment: I changed the [tag:mysql] to [tag:sql-server] which I think is correct because of your `TABLE.dbo.siparis` syntax.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the specific error, but this is wrong:

```
exec trn_boyutlu_siparis_olustur , @siparis_id=Select id FROM TABLE.dbo.siparis where kayit_tarihi=(SELECT MAX(kayit_tarihi) FROM TABLE.dbo.siparis ) , @TargetDb=Database
```

Perhaps your intention is:

```
declare @siparis_id int;

Select @siparis_id = id 
from TABLE.dbo.siparis
where kayit_tarihi = (SELECT MAX(kayit_tarihi) FROM TABLE.dbo.siparis );

exec trn_boyutlu_siparis_olustur @siparis_id=@siparis_id, @TargetDb='Database'
```

I suspect that everything that you are doing is poorly thought out.  If you want to capture ids being returned by an `insert`, then an `output` clause is the right thing to do.  Perhaps you should ask another question with sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you want to accomplish.

Comment: That could be even further simplified by using top 1 id order by kayit_tarihi since the subquery is the same table.